# in tic tac toe I have type extra pair of code for the occupied position, but inst working

Tags: python

I have type extra pair of code for the occupied position, if the player types already typed or occupied position it should return Position not available... but t isn't working at all. just check my code represented with ###### below
where are the mistakes...... help me out

print('Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!')

while True:

```
board = ['#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']

turn=choose_first()

print(turn)

player1,player2 = player_input()



while True:

    if turn=='Player1 goes first':

        display_board(board)

       

        while True:

            s=player_choice(board)

            if space_check(board, s):

                place_marker(board,player1,s)

                display_board(board)

                break

            else:

                print('Position not available') ###### why this part isn't working even after I type the occupied position (which

                continue     ###### as per code should have shown position not available)

        if win_check(board, player1):

            display_board(board)

            print('Congratulations! You have won the game!')

            break

        else:

            if full_board_check(board):

                display_board(board)

                print('The game is a draw!')

                break

            else:

                turn = 'Player2 goes first'

    else:

        display_board(board)

        while True:

            s=player_choice(board)

            if space_check(board, s):

                place_marker(board,player2,s)

                display_board(board)

                break

            else:

                print('Position not available') ###### why this part isn't working even after I type the occupied position (which

                continue    ###### as per code should have shown position not available)

        if win_check(board, player2):

            display_board(board)

            print('Congratulations! player 2 have won the game!')

            break

        else:

            if full_board_check(board):

                display_board(board)

                print('The game is a draw!')

                break

            else:

                turn = 'Player1 goes first'

       

if not replay():

    break
```

Comment: Is there an error in the code... Can you give us the traceback?

Comment: Assuming "space_check" is the function that checks for an already filled space, that is the code we would need to see.